# Visualization of discrete and continous Data

Tags: visualization, multivariate-partition

I want to visualize several variables of discrete and continous data in one Plot.
Does anybody have suggestions for visualization examples or where I should have a look?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the vtree R package https://nbarrowman.github.io/vtree